# How to create a countdown timer that shows hours, minutes and seconds in unity?

Tags: unity, c#, gui

Kind of an easy question but everything I have found on this topic is either outdated or only counts down numbers and not time which is what I need. How can I go about creating a countdown timer where I can input a public float or int for time and then the text on screen will count it down to zero in a time format (00:00:00).

For example if I input "120" (or whatever the proper way to input time is) for instance, then the countdown timer would format correctly to "02:00" then start counting down by seconds. The tutorials ive seen just count down by numbers and dont take time into account (120,119,118, etc)

On top of that I am confused on how to implement a way to activate scripts at a certain time, for example at "1:00" left I would like to send a warning message or something. Please help and thanks!

Comment: I'm confused... Why would formatting a time string as a countdown in Unity be any different from doing it in any other kind of C# program? You remembered to [search for existing solutions first](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+format+countdown), right? Please ask one question at a time. If you have a separate question about triggering a script at a set time, that should be posted as its own question.

Answer (score 2):

### Keeping track of time

You likely already figured out that the best way to keep track of time left in Unity is to have a `private float` variable which gets initialized to the starting time and then gets reduced by Time.deltaTime in the `Update` method:

```
secondsLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
```

### Creating a UI timer

But the problem is that Unity does not provide a comfortable way to format a number of seconds in a float-variable in a human-readable format. But fortunately there is a class for that in the C# standard library: The class [`TimeSpan`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netcore-3.1).

```
TimeSpan timeSpanLeft = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsLeft) ;
```

Create a text element on your UI canvas and set its text like this:

```
yourUiTextElement.text = timeSpanLeft.ToString();
```

The method ToString of TimeSpan by default gets you the time left in the format `hh:mm:ss.ffffff`. If you want to omit the milliseconds, you can also pass [a format string](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings?view=netcore-3.1) to it. If you always want it in the format hh:mm:ss, you would call it like that:

```
yourUiTextElement.text = timeSpanLeft.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

### Handle events when the timer reaches a certain value

A common beginner mistake is to write code like that and expect it to trigger reliable:

```
if(secondsLeft == 60.0f) { // <- WRONG!
```

`Time.deltaTime` skips ahead in unpredictable intervals, so while you can expect a value controlled by it to be larger or smaller than a constant, you can never expect it to be *exactly equal* to a constant. You must not check if there are *exactly* 60 seconds left, because it's more likely than not that the value will change from a little over `60.0` to a little under `60.0` between two updates. You can only check if there are *60 seconds or less* left. And in order to only trigger the event once and not every single update after the 60 second mark, you also need a bool variable which keeps track of whether this event has already happened or not.

```
if(secondsLeft <= 60.0f && warningDisplayed == false) { 
     // display the warning message
     warningDisplayed = true;
}
```